# Issue with storing and retrieving registry key stored in HKLM

Tags: windows, powershell, registry, registrykey

I store a credential in HKLM:/Software/test path and then consume it later for authorization.

I am facing an issue here where sometimes it returns the exact value that I have set, and sometimes it returns a different value. But I can't check the exact registry keys since I don't have physical access of that machine.

So couple of questions around this-
a) Can there be two HKLM accounts in a machine? According to all the docs online, No. But I can't think of any other way to justify this. I am not caching the value explicitly, not sure if windows does that internally.
b) I have also observed that sometimes the flow fails to retrieve that registry key(the test-path commandlet returns false) but for a very short duration, and then it starts returning the correct value again. Does anyone have any context on this? Can it be related to regedit writes? If yes, what's the recommended fix then?

Can someone please help me here? I am running out of options now.

Comment: Storing a credential in a machine's registry is **very** unsafe. Everyone with permissions can then get a hold of it. Please show us the code you use to [1] create that registry credential value and [2] read that value back from a remote pc.

Comment: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` is not an account. It's a predefined handle for a "MACHINE" registry key on a given machine. If it's actually the local machine instead of an RPC connection to a remote machine, the API opens and uses a real handle for the system key object "\REGISTRY\MACHINE", and the "SOFTWARE" subkey is the local registry hive "%SystemRoot%\System32\config\SOFTWARE". Accessing the "SOFTWARE" subkey may be redirected to "SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node" depending on whether the accessing process is a WOW64 process and whether `KEY_WOW64_32KEY` or `KEY_WOW64_64KEY` access is specifically requested.

Comment: @Theo a) Here is what I am using to store the value:

registryPath = "HKLM:\\Software\\test\\AToken” 
`powershell.exe New-Item -Path #{registryPath} -Force; New-ItemProperty -Path #{registryPath} -Name "Token" -Value "#{credentials}”` 

and to retrieve it back, 
we are using `powershell.exe (Get-ItemProperty -Path #{registryPath}).Token`

b) What are other recommended ways to store the credential, which we later want to use to authorize the caller?

Comment: @ErykSun It's a local machine. I asked the owner to check if the key is present in WOW6432Node. It's not present there.